# Is READ_GSERVICES permission still required for Google Maps?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

To add Google Maps to your android application, you need to include a few permissions:

```
<!-- Required -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<!-- Optional -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

However, by checking [Google Maps Android API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#specify_permissions) documentation again, I noticed that

```
com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES
```

is no longer required. I tested it by removing it from `AndroidManifest.xml` and the map is loading fine without any problems.

So, my question is.. what is/was the purpose of `READ_GSERVICES` permission?

Note: Even though it is removed from Google Maps Android API v2 documentation, it can be found on 
[Google Maps API for Business](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/mobile/android/config#specifying_permissions) documentation.

Answer (score 12):

All permissions you need for `Google Maps Android API` [are in the docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/config#specify_android_permissions):

> You must also request the android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.
>   Note: If you're targeting the Android M SDK (23) and the latest version of the Google Play services SDK (8.1), you no longer need the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.
>   From the next release of the Google Play services SDK, the requirement for the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission will be completely dropped from the Google Maps Android API.

So the answer is NO, you don't need it if you use current latest GPS, i.e. 8.1.0.

Comment: user2896182 is specific about com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES and you answered about WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

Comment: user2896182 also asked a different question in his description than the one specified in the title. That question isn't answered, which is what Zhang probably means. EDIT: That question is apparently asked before: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/98330/what-is-the-android-permission-write-gservices-doing

Answer (score 4):

**NO, This persimmons is no longer required in google MAP API V2**

```
    <permission
                 android:name="phonelocation.example.asuss550c.phonelocation.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
                 android:protectionLevel="signature" />  
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
```

**You only need to add**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Also this MetaData in your Application Tag

```
   <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```