# google removed my android app" Issue: Violation of Usage of Android Advertising ID policy and section 4.8 of the Developer Distribution Agreement

Tags: android

I got an email that my android app is removed by google:

in that its mentioned that:

```
Alternatively, you may opt-out of this requirement by removing any requests for sensitive permissions or user data.
```

I have the following permissions in Android Manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> <!-- is required for volley -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

and the following is my android build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxxx.yyyyyy"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.2"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.borjabravo:readmoretextview:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Which are the permission or lib that are causing the privacy problem

Comment: Firs: Do you have a privacy policy? do you have an explanation in your privacy policy regarding the Dangerous Permissions you are asking for? 
Here is a list of Dangerous permissions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36937109/5223744

Comment: is there any google official page which lists the permissions as dangerous or not

Comment: Try this link:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview

Do you have a privacy policy linked in your Google play console?

Comment: The question shouldn't be focused on permissions, I think it should more be focused on Privacy Policy and if these permissions have been taken into consideration within your Privacy Policy.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [Android Runtime Permissions](https://vmokshagroup.com/blog/android-runtime-permissions/)

> The **Dangerous permissions** are the permissions which give application access to the user’s private data or affect the system/other apps. If you list a dangerous permission in manifest then the user has to explicitly give permission to your application.

If you take a look at that list you can see that **com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES** is a dangerous permission, that causes the violation.

*EDIT*: If you have that permission because you use Google Maps, you can safely remove it as [it is not required anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24618806/10614791).

Comment: This permission is added by firebase auth as part of reCAPTCHA library. Are you sure this is correct? I can't find any reference to READ_GSERVICES in your links (they no longer work).

Comment: Well I answered this 5 years ago, so very likely it is outdated at this point, haha. I don't do Android development anymore, so can't tell for sure.